# Auto Update Timestamp in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, automation, timestamp

I'm currently working on a sheet that has to automatically insert todays date in a cell, if another cell is = "Yes"

I currently have this line of code (that I found online):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim cell As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In Target
            cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Now
            cell.Offset(0, 4).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        Next cell
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The problem is that the updated cell in row K is being updated every time the cell is changed, and it should only be updated when the cell in row G = "Yes"

I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Did to try for example to set range like G:2 or G:3 ?

Comment: What cell in G:G?

Comment: Just to be clear. The line of code works, but I need to limited it to only be active when a specific valued it applied. The sheet is setup like a database, so each row holds information about one item.
As of now when G:3 is change then K:3 gets a timestamp. If G:7 is changed then K:7 gets a timestamp.

Comment: I am afraid that nothing is clear in the way you explain...Please define what "specific valued it applied" means. Where in your code do you put or tried putting such a condition? What cell in G:G to be "yes"? The one you try changing?

Comment: `If cell.Value = "Yes" Then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim cell As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In Target
            If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
                cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Now
                cell.Offset(0, 4).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

We test the value of each entry!

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is solved easily - just add an `If` to check the content of the cell:

```
    For Each cell In Target
        If UCase(cell.Value2) = "YES" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Now
            cell.Offset(0, 4).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        Next cell
   Next cell
```

However, your check for column 'G' is flawed. `Target` contains all cells that are currently modified. If the user enter something into a cell, `Target` will contain exactly that cell. If, however, data is for example pasted into that sheet, `Target` will contain all cells where data is pasted into.

Now, `Intersect` checks if two ranges have common cells. Your statement `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing` will check if *any* of the modified cells is in column G and if yes, it will write the date into the cell that is 4 columns to the right. In the case the user enter something into a cell of column G, that's okay. But if he pastes something into, let's say, cells of columns F,G,H, the code will run for all three cells. So you should check each cell individually.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo change_exit    ' Ensure that events are re-enabled in case of error
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Range("G:G"))
        If UCase(cell.Value2) = "YES" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Now
            cell.Offset(0, 4).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        end if
    Next cell
change_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Update**: Changed the logic by just looping over the cells of `target` that intersect with column `G` - thanks to BigBen for the hint.

Comment: Or alternatively loop the `Intersect`ion of `Target` and column G... but yes, good point.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, and your explanation. I'm still learning and your explanation though me something :)